# Assign the old value of dropdown to the same dropdown after edit button clicked in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm losing the dropdown list values while clicking edit button. I'm trying to get the value and assign it to the dropdown but I'm getting error saying -

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It should not reset until we change the dropdown.

aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cat Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCatId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 

"Categoryname") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="20px" />
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="20px" />
 <FooterStyle Width="20px" /> 
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Categoryname")%>' 

Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="DDl_CateName" runat="server" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!

=13);" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DDl_AddCateName" runat="server" onkeydown="return 

(event.keyCode!=13);" >
                  </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

aspx.cs code

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvDaySubmission.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            DropDownList ddlCategories = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDl_CateName");
            string query = "select * from tbl_Category";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            ddlCategories.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            ddlCategories.DataTextField = "Categoryname";
            ddlCategories.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
            ddlCategories.DataBind();
            ddlCategories.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblCategory") as Label).Text).Selected = true;//getting error in this line
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code and checked if your dropdown has the item which you are trying to find? What value you are getting in `lblCategory`?

Comment: im getting values , in lblCategory= "Images", but after that object ref error coming

Comment: i chcked like this , Label LblCat = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblCategory");//images

Comment: Yup that because it is not able to find "Images" in ddlCategories items collection. Have you debugged and checked if it contains such value?

Comment: in datasource of ddl . there is images item.

Comment: You need to check if there are any white spaces, use `Trim` method and from DB send the values without any space using `LTRIM` & `RTRIM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because, the label text you are trying to find might not be present or it may contain whitespace in dropdown collection. You can avoid this error like this:-

```
string category = (e.Row.FindControl("lblCategory") as Label).Text;
ListItem item = ddlCategories.Items.FindByText(category);
if(item != null)
    item.Selected = true;
```

Comment: ListItem items = ddlCategories.Items.FindByValue(category);//categore=Articlesites
but items getting null

Comment: @krishnamohan - And what about `item`?

Comment: in ListItem object its not storing findbyvalue(categories)

Comment: @krishnamohan - Yeah then obviously it is not able to find that item in dropdown collection.

Comment: @krishnamohan - Hey buddy your DataValueField is `CategoryId` and you are passing text field. You should use `FindByText` instead of `FindByValue`. Check my update.